# How to manually sort/arrange a Power BI funnel chart?

Tags: sorting, charts, powerbi-desktop

I have searched all over for an answer to this, including Microsoft's Power BI documentation, but I have not been able to find a solution. I did find a Microsoft document that said "funnel charts can be sorted", but then it did not go on to explain HOW to do that!

My funnel chart is sorting by default from the item with the highest count on top to the item with the lowest count on bottom. That is to be expected from a funnel chart, but we want to sort our chart in a specific order that has to do with the chronology of landing a new customer.

Here is how Power BI sorts our data by default:

Power BI funnel chart in the default sorted order:
[image: Power BI funnel chart in the default sorted order]

However, this puts the items out of chronological order, so we want it sorted as follows to represent the life cycle of a customer from initial lead to a signed contract:

Power BI funnel chart the way we'd like to sort it:
[image: Power BI funnel chart the way we'd like to sort it]

I tried adding numbers in front of our category names to override the sorting (e.g. 1.Prospect, 2.Qualified Lead, 3.Contract Sent, 4.Signed Customer), but that did not work.

Is there a way to manually order the items in a funnel chart? Many thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 2):

I managed to answer my own question! I was on the right track previously when I added the numbers in front of the labels (e.g. 1.Prospect, 2.Qualified Lead, 3.Contract Sent, 4.Signed Customer). But I assumed that Power BI would then sort by that grouped value, when in fact you have to manually force it to do so by clicking the "More options" (three dots) icon in the upper right corner of the element. Then choose "Sort by", select the Group you want to sort by, and then choose "Sort Ascending".

The result is exactly what we were looking for:

[Funnel Chart sorted by group:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDf8i.png)

Of course, if you don't want the numbers in front of your labels, then I still don't know how to do that natively in Power BI, but this work-around will meet our needs for now.

Comment: Thanks this helped me out! To get rid of the 1, 2, etc., I used spaces, 1 space, 2 space, 3 space, and when I went to sort it PowerBI sent the one with 1 space before the words up to the top :)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try this paid custom visual: https://zoomcharts.com/en/microsoft-power-bi-custom-visuals/custom-visuals/drill-down-column-line-area-chart/

It does offer sorting to control the display as necessary.

Janis

Disclaimer: I am co-founder of ZoomCharts

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a hack: sometimes you can add the column you want to sort on, in the 'tooltips' field of the visual. This does not change the visual, but you can then (through the three dots on the visual) select that field to order the data on.